# What is the difference between mapped_column and Column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy and I see that in the documentation the older version (Column) can be swapped directly with the newer "mapped_column".

Is there any advantage to using mapped_column over Column? Could you stick to the older 'Column'?

Comment: [This section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#overview) of the docs adds some context to why it was introduced.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think originally `Column` was used in the lower "core"/`sqlalchemy.sql` layer **AND** the higher ORM layer.  This created a conflict of purpose.  So `mapped_column` now supersedes `Column` when using the ORM layer to add more functionality that can't be used by the core layer.  The core layer will keep using `Column`.  So I think it is just meant to help you do more faster or more succinctly with the ORM.

There is a blurb about them titled "mapped_column() supersedes the use of Column()" below [declarative-table-with-mapped-column](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column).

### Here are some basic examples, using postgresql.

See `SQL` output at end.

```py
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Controller(Base):
    __tablename__ = "controllers"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column() # Example 1
    index: Mapped[int] # Example 2
    configured: Mapped[Optional[bool]] # Example 3
    setup_mode: Mapped[bool] # Example 4
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True)) # Example 5
```

##### Example 1

The column type is derived from the type hint, `VARCHAR` is derived from `str` in this case.

```py
name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
```

##### Example 2

When `mapped_column` would be empty it can be left out entirely and this still works, ie. `INTEGER` is derived from `int`.

```py
index: Mapped[int]
```

#### Example 3

When `Optional` from `typing` is used then a column will allow `NULL`, ie. `nullable=True`.

```py
configured: Mapped[Optional[bool]]
```

#### Example 4

When `Optional` is **NOT** used then a column will not allow `NULL`, ie. `nullable=False`.

```py
setup_mode: Mapped[bool]
```

#### Example 5

`Column` can still be used alongside `mapped_column` without using type hints at all.

```py
created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

#### Example of type checking

Running this code through `mypy` will produce an error similar to `error: "Controller" has no attribute "unknown_attribute"  [attr-defined]`

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    controller = session.scalars(select(Controller).limit(1)).first()
    if controller is not None:
        assert controller.created_at
        assert controller.unknown_attribute
```

### Final `CREATE TABLE` output

```sql
CREATE TABLE controllers (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    index INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    configured BOOLEAN, 
    setup_mode BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

### Some "Why"s

- allow more orm specific functionality that does not make sense to be in `Column()`
- reduce boilerplate code

  - `int`, `str`, `datetime`, `Optional`, etc. are available from python without needing `sqlalchemy` imports
  - In cases where the type can be derived from the typehint and no special configuration is necessary the entire column/mapped_column definition can be left out, ie. `index: Mapped[int]`
- allow type checkers to better check types

  - the checks can be expanded by using something like the data-class integration but is beyond this question

Comment: Moreover, it directly supports typing, so you can do `col: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)`.

Comment: Maybe this answer could give some examples of the added functionality? From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column), it sounds like `mapped_column` is mainly introduced to support type hints and typing tools, much like the rest of the SQLA 2.0 additions. The docs also mention it's a drop-in replacement while using language like "...migration to the new form can be at any pace", which suggest it might be expected to replace `Column` eventually.

Comment: I don't see how it could replace `Column` at the core layer because the `Table` constructor or factory expects a variable number of `Column` arguments.  It does seem like it might become the more common usage when using declarative+ORM but even then I think `Column` will always work.  The "migration to the new form can be at any pace" note I think is just to explain that if you want to use it then you don't have to migrate everything at once, you can migrate a line at a time if necessary.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund I added some more examples.